# No tests run in maven project with karate module

Tags: karate

We have a multi module project with the following structure

- module 1
- module 2
- module e2e
- parent pom

The module e2e contains our karate features (into the src/test/java/features folder)

We couldn't figure out how to run the karate tests using the "mvn test".
It always runs 0 tests, instead there are some feature files.

We have tried running "mvn test" from the root of the project, as well as from inside the e2e module

We have other maven projects (not multi module) and it works as expected.
Does it necessary to make some configuration action to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ops, sorry. I forgot. Now it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn test` behind the scenes just looks for JUnit tests, it is that simple. Check that your JUnit class names end with `Test` - and that the maven tweak for the recommended directory structure is in place: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/724

Otherwise unless you follow this process, it is difficult for anyone to help you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter. My Class ends with `Test`. I am going to check the directory structure as you suggest. Really appreciate.

Comment: There was a mistake in my folder structure. Now it works fine. Thanks a lot.